# LDAPS configuration for IBM MobileFirst v8 Login Authenticator

Tags: java, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I tried to move from ldap to ldaps for Login authenticator.

In adapter.xml

```
<property name="ldapURL" defaultValue="ldap://10.10.10.10:10636" displayName="The LDAP Server URL"/>
```

In LoginAuthenticator class

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
```

I get the following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I do not know, where I need to put my keystore to hit in ldaps protocol. Can you please help me?

I tried putting it in the following path with server.xml configurations, but no luck.

```
E:\MobileFirst-8.0.0.0\mfp-server\usr\servers\mfp\resources\security

<sslDefault sslRef="mySSLSettings" />
<ssl id="mySSLSettings" keyStoreRef="LDAPKeyStore" clientAuthentication="true" />
<keyStore id="LDAPKeyStore" location="serverssl.ks" type="JKS" password="secret" />
```

Comment: What login authenticator class? In v8 there is no such thing as "login authenticator".

Comment: Look here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/17/connecting-to-LDAP-with-ibm-mobilefirst-foundation/

Comment: It is LDAP LoginAuthenticator.

Comment: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/17/connecting-to-LDAP-with-ibm-mobilefirst-foundation/

Comment: I tried the steps given in the page, but I have issues in placing the keystore. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by marabu, if you add the CA certificates of your LDAP server to Liberty's trust store, it might solve your problem.

Where you need to add depends on how you have configured your trust store.

Going by the ssl configuration snippet you have pasted and assuming you have not defined the truststore via jvm.options or added it in MobileFoundation's keystore in MobileFoundation console, your serverssl.ks would act as both keystore as well as trust store.

So if you add the CA certificates of your LDAP server to serverssl.ks and restart the server, it should work I feel.
You can add a CA certificate to your keystore by executing this command,

```
keytool -importcert -keystore serverssl.ks -alias <your_alias> -file <yourcacert.pem>
```

Comment: I also tried keytool and imported serverssl.ks. I still get the same error. What is  MobileFoundation's keystore in MobileFoundation console? I guess, it only for configuring the mobilefirst keystore. I am not sure. Can you please share more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

You wonder about the keystore, but the error message is about your truststore.  The backend presents its (presumably self-signed certificate or a self-owned CA) certificate to your adapter during the SSL handshake.  Your adapter tries to walk the chain of trust by looking for the issuers certificate recursively in your truststore.

Either you didn't import the backend certificate chain into your truststore or your adapter isn't using the truststore you configured.

Comment: my adapter isn't using the configured truststore - this is the issue! How can make my adapter use this?